# Pull implementation in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java2

I'm developing a testing library and I would like to implement a pull implementation using RxJava

I have a stream (all available tests) with several observers subscribed (all testing devices) and I would like that when each subscriber finish the processing of an element request a new element to the stream, and all stream elements should be processed just by one consumer.

I'm wondering if this can be implemented this using a hot observable and using backpressure techniques but I don't really sure about this :(

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need something like a [`WorkDispatchProcessor`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#dispatchworkprocessor).

Comment: I have been working on this and I have seen that using `request(1)` from my subscriber I'm able to control de stream flow over the devices, but... I'm getting all the elements in each subscriber, so each element is processed N times. I want to distribute all flowable elements over the devices and each flowable element should be processed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, with the help of @akarnokd, I found the solution to this. Here is the code:

```
        Subscriber sub1=new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        Subscription subscription;

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            this.subscription = s;
            s.request(1);
            System.out.println("onSubscribe done");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer t) {
            System.out.println("Sub 1 Processing: "+t);
            sleep(1000);
            subscription.request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) { }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() { }
    };

    Subscriber sub2=new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        Subscription subscription;

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            this.subscription = s;
            s.request(1);
            System.out.println("onSubscribe done");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer t) {
            System.out.println("Sub2 Processing: "+t);
            sleep(500);
            subscription.request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) { }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() { }
    };

    // ***** Magic happens here!! *****
    DispatchWorkProcessor<Integer> dwp = DispatchWorkProcessor.create(Schedulers.io());
    Flowable.range(1, 20).subscribe(dwp);
    dwp.subscribe(sub1);
    dwp.subscribe(sub2);
    // ********************************

    sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

The trick was the use of `request(1)` to implement the pull approach and the `DispatchWorkProcessor` to consume the elements once from the stream. In spite of the speed of one consumer is twice the output is as expected:

```
onSubscribe done
onSubscribe done
Sub 1 Processing: 1
Sub2 Processing: 2
Sub2 Processing: 3
Sub 1 Processing: 4
Sub2 Processing: 5
Sub2 Processing: 6
Sub 1 Processing: 7
Sub2 Processing: 8
Sub2 Processing: 9
Sub 1 Processing: 10
Sub2 Processing: 11
Sub2 Processing: 12
Sub 1 Processing: 13
Sub2 Processing: 14
Sub2 Processing: 15
Sub 1 Processing: 16
Sub2 Processing: 17
Sub2 Processing: 18
Sub 1 Processing: 19
Sub2 Processing: 20
```

All the stream elements are processed once and Sub 2 process a double number of elements, which is nice!